# How to disable Decomposition Tree in Analytic Grid

Tags: 2013, performancepoint, dashboard-designer-2013

I am using PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer with SharePoint 2013. I have several Analytic Grids. When I right click the Analytic Grid, it shows several options like **Decomposition Tree, Show Details, Additional Actions** and so on. Is there any way we can hide/disable those three options for selected Analytic Grids or Charts.

[image]

Thanks,
Merin

Comment: hello did you find a solution for the above ?

Comment: Nope! Not yet! Are you trying to do the same thing or you just asked because of curiosity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily some one did it on his blog for me. https://electrovoid.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/pps-hide-show-details/